# Post to a Facebook Page without an user account

Tags: php, facebook

I have to following code:

```
<?php
class Facebook
{       
    /**
     * @var The page id to edit
     */
    private $page_id = '134470319994206';   

    /**
     * @var the page access token given to the application above
     */
    private $page_access_token = 'xxx'; 

    /**
     * @var The back-end service for page's wall
     */
    private $post_url = '';

    /**
     * Constructor, sets the url's
     */
    public function Facebook()
    {
        $this->post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->page_id.'/feed';
    }

    /**
     * Manages the POST message to post an update on a page wall
     * 
     * @param array $data
     * @return string the back-end response
     * @private
     */
    public function message($data)
    {   
        // need token
        $data['access_token'] = $this->page_access_token;

        // init
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->post_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // execute and close
        $return = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // end
        return $return;        
    }
}

$facebook = new Facebook();

var_dump($facebook->message(array( 'message'     => 'A sample message' ) ) );
```

Now, when I execute the code, boolean false is returned. Could someone explain me how to do this without having an account, because I just want a page, and the ability to post to it with PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: You are not allowed without an account. You need an authorization, thus an account.

Comment: a page can be created only by a user and you'll need that user (or some other page admin) to obtain the access token